# Why is stack smashing detected if an empty array[] is initiated in the constructor < 2 inside a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am running into this error...
[image]

...with this minimal executable code to reproduce the error and ...

```c++
#include <iostream>

class arrayClass
{
private:
   int _elements;
   int _array[];

public:
    arrayClass()
        : _elements(32)
    {
        //If i is smaller than 2 the "Stack Smashing Detected" error shows up, why is that?
        //If i is 2 or more, no error appears
        //(f.e. int i = 0 or int i = 1 doesn't work, int i = 2 or higher works - why is that?)
        for(int i = 0; i < _elements; ++i){
            _array[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    int get(int index){
        return _array[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    arrayClass arr;
    std::cout << arr.get(2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

...it doesn't matter if I initiate _elements with the initialization list or at with the
attribute itself with f.e.32 or whatever number.

If I pass the int value to construct the `arrayClass(int)` in addition to the arrayClass() constructor, the error doesn't shows up.

If I construct the arrayClas(int) with a value alone, it can also just be used with the 2nd slot upwards.

**So my question is:
Why couldn't I initiate the 1st and 2nd array slot of a default `array[]`?**

**Or the other way around, why is it possible to assign an empty `array[]` to a class without a value and not f.e. _array[32] without an error but the one with assigning `array[0] = 0;` and `array[1] = 0;` ?**

*(And yes, I am aware of vectors, I need to use arrays for various reasons)*

Comment: ISO C++ forbids flexible arrays. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: You're using a flexible array member, which was introduced into C in 1999, and is illegal in C++. Unfortunately, some C++ compilers support it as a non-standard extension. Your code treats it like an array of arbitrary size, but it is not that - it's usage in C requires allocation of memory large enough to hold both the structure AND a specified number of elements. Your code is not allocating that additional memory, so treating `_arr` as if it has ANY (i.e. more than zero) elements overwrites some random area of memory - which in your case is being reported as stack smashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you never allocate memory for the array to begin with, everything is undefined behavior.  I don't even know what `int _array[]` evaluates to without a size specifier. I'll look that up later.

Change your construct code to "new" the array.  And have a destructor to delete it.

```
class arrayClass
{
private:
   int _elements;
   int* _array;

public:
    arrayClass()
        : _elements(32)
    {
        _array = new int[_elements];
        memset(_array, '\0', sizeof(array[0])*_elements);
    }
    int get(int index){
        return _array[index];
    }

    ~arrayClass()
    {
        delete [] _array;
    }
};
```

Or if you can have a fixed number of elements, explictly size the array when it's declared:

```
class arrayClass
{
private:
   int _array[32];

public:
    arrayClass()
        : _array() // this will zero-init the array
    {
    }
    int get(int index){
        return _array[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't do manual memory management but use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - agreed. I just want the OP to learn how pointers work to understand the root of his issue.

Comment: The OP does explicitly say I can't use vectors.

Comment: `memset(_array, '\0', sizeof(_array[0])*_elements);` and you may also provide something to avoid multiple deletion of `_array`, for example, a private copy constructor.

Comment: Really nice, that is what I was searching for - also with the "zero-init" hint ! Thanks a lot! Safes me lots of time  and writing :)

Answer (score 2):

`int _array[];` is a *flexible array* and isn't allowed in standard C++. It does not allocate memory so when you access any element in the array, you have undefined behavior.

> I am aware of vectors, I need to use arrays for various reasons

In reality there are very few valid reasons so I expect the various reasons you mention to be artificial. If you need to pass the data to a function, like `void func(int*, size_t elements);`, you can still use a `std::vector<int>`. Just pass its `data()` and `size()` as arguments.

In C++ you should typically use a `std::vector<int>` for cases like this.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class arrayClass
{
private:
   std::vector<int> _array;

public:
    arrayClass(size_t s = 32)
        : _array(s)
    {}

    size_t size() const {
        return _array.size();
    }

    int get(size_t index) const {
        return _array[index];
    }
};

int main()
{
    arrayClass arr;
    std::cout << arr.get(10) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

An alternative, if your `arrayClass` has a fixed number of elements:

```
#include <array>

class arrayClass
{
private:
   std::array<int, 32> _array;

public:
    arrayClass()
        : _array{}
    {}

    size_t size() const {
        return _array.size();
    }

    int get(size_t index){
        return _array[index];
    }
};
```

---

If the extra space a `std::vector` consumes (usually 4 or 8 bytes) is a real concern, you could make a similar class that only stores the pointer to the allocated memory and the size. It could look like this (but doesn't have the ability to grow/shrink like a `vector` has):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>* = nullptr>
class arrayClass {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    arrayClass(size_t size = 32) :
        _size(size),
        _array(std::make_unique<T[]>(_size))
    {}

    // copy constructor
    arrayClass(const arrayClass& rhs) :
        _size(rhs._size),
        _array(std::make_unique<T[]>(_size))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>, "T must be copy assignable");
        std::copy(rhs._array.get(), rhs._array.get() + _size, _array.get());
    }

    arrayClass(arrayClass&&) = default; // move constructor

    // copy assignment operator    
    arrayClass& operator=(const arrayClass& rhs) {
        *this = arrayClass(rhs); // copy construct and move assign
        return *this;
    }

    arrayClass& operator=(arrayClass&&) = default; // move assignment operator

    // accessing element at index
    T& operator[](size_t index) { return _array[index]; }
    const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return _array[index]; }

    // bounds checking access to element
    T& at(size_t idx) {
        if(idx >= _size) 
           throw std::out_of_range(std::to_string(idx) + ">=" + std::to_string(_size));
        return _array[idx];
    }
    const T& at(size_t idx) const {
        if(idx >= _size)
           throw std::out_of_range(std::to_string(idx) + ">=" + std::to_string(_size));
        return _array[idx];
    }

    size_t size() const { return _size; }

    // support for iterating over the elements in the array
    const T* cbegin() const { return _array.get(); }
    const T* cend() const { return _array.get() + _size; }
    const T* begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const T* end() const { return cend(); }
    T* begin() { return _array.get(); }
    T* end() { return _array.get() + _size; }   

private:
   size_t _size;
   std::unique_ptr<T[]> _array;
};

using intArray = arrayClass<int>;

int main() {
    try {
        intArray arr1(10);
        // the added iterator support makes range-based for-loops possible:
        for(int& v : arr1) {
            static int i=0;
            v = ++i;
        }

        intArray arr2;
        arr2 = arr1; // copy assign
        for(size_t i=0; i < arr2.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << arr2[i] << '\n';       // access using operator[] works too
        }    

        std::cout << arr2.at(10) << '\n'; // throws out_of_range exception
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: No, sadly not just artificial. One of many reasons "These abilities come at a price: vectors consume more memory in exchange for the ability to handle storage and growing dynamically in size. vector<int> v; where v is the variable of type Vector store integer elements." https://www.educba.com/c-plus-plus-vector-vs-array/ 

Sure no problem for the average computer. My use case is for arduinos/teensy boards and openWRT router with really sacred space available. Thanks for your answer, goten an upvote anyhow. Wasn't aware a flexible array isn't allowed in standard c++, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Ivanovic Sure, every vector has some **fixed** memory overhead (often 4 or 8 bytes), but other than that, it's very similar to storing the pointer returned by `new int[size]` and storing `size`. I've used vectors successfully on arduinos and I would not replace them to save those few bytes until I've actually run out of memory and thought that saving 4 or 8 bytes per vector would do the trick.

Comment: @Ivanovic I added an example if you are serious about saving those few bytes.

Comment: Holy guacamole, that's a nice piece of code you added right there! Never even heard of a 'move constructor' - Lots to learn, thanks mate! 

Yeah, the weakest link in the chain is a 4096k router - so it has to be down to that. I guess even templates are out in that - but yeah, challenge accepted! Thanks for your work again, would like to give you way more upvotings!

Comment: @Ivanovic You're welcome. :) The class template shouldn't be a problem. Each instance doesn't take more space than a non-template class, so if you use it for `int` only, you'll only have one instance.